# Context: "Squashing Functions and Neural Networks"

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, machine-learning, neural-networks

I hope your lives have been proceeding along well.

Lately, I have been reading about squashing functions in the context of neural networks. Specifically, the book I am working through, *Deep Learning Architectures* by Ovidiu Calin, discusses squashing functions in its section on activation functions, but does not really provide any explanation regarding the significance of these functions, which use cases suit them best, or frankly how they are used in practice (either in implementations or proofs). Does anyone here have some remarks on where exactly squashing functions come into use with neural networks? Perhaps I am not seeing something obvious, but I would really appreciate any help with better situating squashing functions in my mental framework of machine learning. To help with this request, here is their description in the book:

#### Definition

A function $\varphi:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ is a squashing function if:

1. It is non-decreasing, i.e., for $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x_1 < x_2$ then $\varphi(x_1) \leq \varphi(x_2)$
2. $\lim_{n\to -\infty} \varphi(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \varphi(x) = 1$

#### Examples

- Step function $H(x) = 1_{[0,\infty)}(x)$
- Ramp function $\varphi(x) = x1_{[0,1]}(x) + 1_{[0,\infty)}(x)$
- Cosine squasher $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(1 + \cos (x + \frac{3\pi}{2}) \bigg) 1_{[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]}(x) + 1_{(\frac{\pi}{2},\infty)}(x)$

Comment: does this help: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/36533/activation-function-vs-squashing-function. A squashing function in this context is considered a function that squashes the input into some smaller range. Some examples (in networks networks) are sigmoid and tanh functions

Comment: @RahulMadhavan This helps somewhat. I just finished reading the discussion and it seems apparent that squashing function are used in capsule networks, which I have not really heard of, and as a means of manipulating output vectors to be representative of some measure. These seem more implementation based details, which are nice, but it would also be great to learn more about how these functions affect neural network topology and performance. I cannot seem to find intuitive descriptions in this regard.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is specific to capsule networks at all. An input to any neuron in a neural network is not necessarily bounded, whereas we may want outputs that fall within a range (say [0,1]). 

Thus we pass the outputs of the neuron through what is known as an activation function. Such activation functions may "squash" the input into a much smaller range (in case of sigmoid and tanh), and may not squash in case of other activation functions like ReLU.

Comment: Coming to performance, if one considers outputs that are not "squashed", then one may have inputs to the next layer that have greater norm or are farther away from the optimum (geometrically). Since gradient descent in NNs often have fixed step size or a deterministically decreasing step size, these larger norms may lead to greater number of iteration steps to reach the optimum.

Comment: Thank you @RahulMadhavan, this is fairly useful, especially the short geometric interpretation; I usually find visualizing these things the most helpful. Maybe I can get a better feel for things with a combing of the literature and maybe doing some practice implementations.